# Hand-written custom shapes recognition

Tags: java, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to implement a small recognition program, which should take an image with hand-written shapes as an input (shape objects can be nested), and tell me which shapes it consists of, their type, size and at least coordinates of one point in a shape.
Where should I start?
Maybe, some machine learning technics could be used for such a task?

I've tried to look for some examples or tutorials dealing with handwriting recognition of custom shapes, but haven't found something worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [Coursera Machine Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) taught by Andrew Ng from Stanford.

It will guide you through techniques of ML resulting in writing your own digit recogniting neural network.

It's really deep field and I believe that simply using some tutorial will be not enough - understanding of subject and techniques that you will use is really important.